# Is it possible to use <%: in .net framework 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, asp.net-mvc-2, encoding

This may be a duplicate of some other question, but it's hard to search the web for `<%:` so I can't really find anything.

When I created a new Asp.net MVC 2 project its templates use the new notation of automatic html encoding. WHen I changed .net framework target to 3.5, these server scripts stopped working. When I changed them to `<%=` everything was fine, but it's not the same.

Anyway. Is it possible to take advantage of this notation and avoid writing tedious and long statements `<%= Html.Encode(...) %>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible. It is mentioned in the following [article](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc). See the section titled **Helpers now return an MvcHtmlString object**. Also, see the [explanation](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/03/html-encoding-nuggets-aspnetmvc2.aspx) from Phil Haack as to why.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is an ASP.NET 4.0 only feature - so on 3.5, you still need to remember to use the `Html.Encode(.....)`..... another good reason to upgrade! :-)

Comment: Well sometimes you can't upgrade because it depends on another product, that's built in 3.5... :(

Comment: Can't you set up assembly binding redirects for those?